# Get result PHP code in jQuery function?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I use codeigniter and i want make uniqid code with php as following code(by random_string()):

```
function coding(){
    echo random_string('unique');
}
```

I want use result top function in a, jquery function (for use in js code), i in jquery code try as this, but this output in `alert(coding())` is "undefined". How can fix it?

```
function coding(){
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        url: "coding",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            return data;
        }
   })
}
alert(coding()) // in here output is  "undefined" !!!?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function coding(){
   var temp;
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        url: coding,
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            temp = data;
        }
   })
   return temp;
}
alert(coding());
```

You will receive an [object XMLDocument].

Comment: Are you sure this will work? AJAX call in asynchronous, so `success` is called when the function `coding()` already returned `temp`. My guess is you will always get `undefined`.

Comment: "async: false" makes the call synchronous

Comment: oops, missed that... true. :) OP should take care though - this means the function will "hang" for the duration of the call. It would be better if OP changed the way he calls the function and use AJAX properly (asynchronously).

Answer (score 1):

It is becuse *coding* function is asynchronous. 
Use follow code:

```
function coding(){
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        url: coding,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
   })
}
coding();
```

Comment: I don't want alert, in above code it have output, but man want use return it as append in other js code, this just done alert result php code. how is it?

Comment: @RamilAmr I vote up for you because you understand his problem

Answer (score 1):

```
function coding(){
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        url: "coding",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#yourDiv").html(data);
        }
   })
}
```

You can assign value to another element like div, p etc.

Comment: @Kate Wintz Alert? I append html to a div, instead of html() you can use append(data);

Comment: @KateWintz are you copy your comment without read my soulution?

Comment: I mean is the same, i want use of name function as "coding()" for echo return this function in other js code. but your code append return in a selector.

Comment: @KateWintz sorry, I think you can't, because this is asynchronous call. You should to include your js to another page

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm assuming that the **coding** variable you are passing at the parameter **url** is a reference to a method in your CI controller.

If that's the case, you just need to wait from the **success** callback:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        url: coding,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
   })
```

Comment: I don't want alert, in above code it have output, but man want use return it as append in other js code, this just done alert result php code. how is it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you should use **callback** function like this:

```
function coding(func){
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        url: coding,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            func(data);
        }
   })
}
coding(function(data)
{
   alert(data);
});
```